# drupal_get_form -- How do I include a JavaScript onClick event into the function results?

Tags: forms, javascript

I have someone else's drupal_get_form code, where I was requested to have the form's button change color after clicking, while the user remains on that page.

The function's *rendered output* looks like this:

```
<form action="/mitreinstitute/my-institute" method="post" id="mi-custom-course-withdrawal-email-form-0" accept-charset="UTF-8">
 <div>
  <input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Withdraw Me" class="form-submit" />
  <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-rpHwdhyCJfun0lRObhtuMWjehzOeNTHOeL9YCY-jQ84" />
  <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="0tnkm6jb6PhZnpTNI16SLMq0XrkhZGKsDax7d3S9hIk" />
  <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="mi_custom_course_withdrawal_email_form_0" />
 </div>
</form>
```

I cannot figure out to incorporate something like this JavaScript onClick function, so that it is merged into the form's rendered *submit* element:

Answer (score 2):

You can add Javascript to a form using the `#attached` property. So either in the form definition, or a hook_form_alter if you're altering a form you didn't code:

```
$form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE') . '/foo.js';
```

In the JS file add what you need to, wrapping it in a Behavior to ensure events are reattached following AJAX calls:

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.MYMODULE = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $('#form-id').once('MYMODULE').submit(function() {
        // Do what you need to here
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```